# SharePoint Modern List - Increase column width with JSON Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to increase the width of a column in a modern SP list.  Here is an image prior to adding JSON:

[image]

As you can see, the width of the "Description" column needs to increase in order to show the content.  So I added this JSON in Column Formatting:

[image]

This script works to adjust the column width, but it messed up the content:

[image]

I'm not sure why this script changed the entries in the description column.  Any help here would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multi-Line Text column with enhanced rich text** are not fully supported using JSON formatting in SharePoint.

**Microsoft Documentation**: [JSON formatting - Supported column types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types)

---

**Update from comments**:

To increase the width of column, try this:

1. Go to SharePoint list. In my list, "Message Body" is a Multi-line text with enhanced rich text column:

   [image]
2. Select the right edge of column header, drag to the right & increase the width like:

   [image]
3. It will look like below image. Also, it will change the current list view & show the ***** in view name:

   [image]
4. Click on the view name from **Switch view options** dropdown (highlighted in yellow in above image) & select **Save view as**.
5. It will open a popup like below. Just click on **Save** without changing anything:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Is there another way I can either expand the width of the column or wrap the text if I'm using Multi-line text with enhanced rich text?

Comment: Check my updated answer. This is the only "easy" way I can suggest to change the width of the column.