# SharePoint Modern Column Header cuts off

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, modern-document-library

I have a Modern SharePoint document library that includes a column header that is slightly too long, and cuts off:

[image]

This "Date Last Declared" column is a Date and Time column. I'm able to write JSON to expand the width of the column, but it only affects the content, not the header.

Is there a way I can either expand the column to fit the header, or wrap the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** format the column headers using JSON formatting in SharePoint online.

But you can manually increase the width of column header by dragging it to the right & save the library view.

For detailed steps, check: [SharePoint Modern List - Increase column width with JSON Issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293683/sharepoint-modern-list-increase-column-width-with-json-issue)

---

**Updates from comments**:

I can re-size the column header & save the view in web part added on SharePoint page as well.

**Document library**: Default document library page

[image]

**Library web part**: library web part added on SharePoint modern page

[image]

Comment: I actually tried doing that manually and saving it as a new view.  The set up is like this...I have a page in which the library is displaying via web part.  When I edited the web part to point to the new view I saved, the column width doesn't apply.

Comment: I just tried this & it is working fine for me. Check screenshots in updated answer.

Comment: Actually it now looks like saving the manually adjusted columns as a new view, and pointing the web part to that view works.  I had to refresh a couple of times, but I think I'm in the clear.  Thanks again for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to hide the OOB column headers and create customized column headers using JSON, you can take a reference to the json code in my answer: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/386485/sharepoint-list-formatting-34hideselection34-does.html

I set `hideColumnHeader` to true and use `rowFormatter` to define a totally custom layout. Then I designed DIV in this part:

```
"children": [
       {
         "elmType": "div",
         "txtContent": "Title",
         "style": {
           "width": "80px"
         }
       },
       {
         "elmType": "div",
         "txtContent": "Departure",
         "style": {
           "width": "100px"
         }
       },
       {
         "elmType": "div",
         "txtContent": "Arrival",
         "style": {
           "width": "100px"
         }
       }
     ]
   },
```

Comment: Thanks for you response.  I'm unclear as to what part of your script would expand the column headers.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my answer.