# Edit SharePoint online list header styles

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, list-view, modern-experience

I am having a SharePoint Online list which has long column names like "Agreement delivered to planned vertical" and "Status of approval from XXXX". In normal view, I'm able to see only cropped text like "Agreement delivered..." and "Status of...". So here I want to display the entire text by text wrapping into second line instead of showing "...", is it possible?

So Column name would be displayed in two or three lines like below

```
Agreement delivered
to planned vertical
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a default behavior in SharePoint online. You cannot wrap the column headers in two or three lines.

But you can manually increase the width of column header by dragging it to the right & save the list view.

[image]

For detailed steps, check: [SharePoint Modern List - Increase column width with JSON Issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293683/sharepoint-modern-list-increase-column-width-with-json-issue)

**Similar thread**: [SharePoint Modern Column Header cuts off](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293760/sharepoint-modern-column-header-cuts-off/293764#293764)

Comment: I'm aware of this, but the requirement is to wrap the column header. Can't we do this by any means like Power apps or SharePoint designer?

Comment: Wrapping header text is not possible using SharePoint out of the box or Power Apps capabilities. You can try developing SPFx application customizer to inject custom CSS for this ( But, injecting custom css/javascript is not recommended by Microsoft).

Comment: Thanks a lot for details!