# Change document library column width

Tags: sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2019, on-prem version, is there a way to increase the width of a column in a document library that is part of the document library web part?  Right now, the full document title is not displaying.

Comment: Are you trying to change the width of column in document library web part that is added on SharePoint site page?

Comment: Yes.  Currently, it is cutting off part of the document title, but I would like to have the full document title display.

Comment: Are you able to drag the column width as mentioned here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293683/sharepoint-modern-list-increase-column-width-with-json-issue/293686#293686

Comment: I'm able to drag the column, but we are using the On-Prem version of SharePoint 2019, and it doesn't give me the option to save my updates.  I wasn't sure if there is a setting where I can adjust the width.  Thanks!

Comment: Does it helps or answers your question?

Comment: I've been looking at other answers and need to help verifying one thing - does the on-premise version allow you to modify colors or other items with CSS?

Comment: It supports JSON formatting if you are trying to apply CSS for list or library to customise the display